# Установка Package Control в Sublime Text на OS Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

Получаю в console данную ошибку при установке Package Control:

```python
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
Error validating download (got 6f4c264a24d933ce70df5dedcf1dcaeeebe013ee18cced0ef93d5f746d80ef60 instead of eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282d0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d), please try manual install
```

Comment: Шаги для воспроизведения опишите; то есть каким образом Вы устанавливали Package Control. Если что, в новых версиях Sublime Text 3 Package Control устанавливается просто — `Tools` → `Install Package Control...` . Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как написано в самой ошибке, возникли проблемы при скачивании пакета. Дело в том, что скачанный файл не соответсвует тому, что должно было быть скачано. Попытайтесь установить этот плагин вручную.

На https://packagecontrol.io/installation справа подробно описан процесс `Manual installation`

Comment: Считаю, что плохая практика — советовать устанавливать вручную, когда не испробован наиболее простой способ: `Tools` → `Install Package Control...` . Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных я лишь указал на то, что написано в ошибке. Да и ручной метод не такой уж и сложный - всего лишь скачать и вставить файл в папку.

Comment: В самой ошибке же сказано - "try manual install", так что всё правильно.

Comment: при установки package settings через cntrl + shift + p выдает данную ошибку в консоли Package Control: Unable to download https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json after 3 attempts

Comment: Сделал все по manual. Вот данная ошибка Package Control

There are no packages available for installation

Please see https://packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting for help

Comment: вы не используете proxy?

Comment: Нет не использую.

Comment: Все-таки мне необходима помощь с установкой Install Packages.